# Command get julian week in DOS

Tags: batch-file, dos

What's the command line in DOS to create Julian week.

In Unix.....I have this command work fine.
date +%Y%W = 201507

In DOS I can get year....but not %W.  Please help.
echo %date:~10,4%

Comment: Are you **really** using MS-DOS? That is long dead and forgotton. (The command line in Windows has *nothing* to do with "DOS")

Comment: horse is correct. Cmd.exe has nothing to do with DOS. In addition, I would recommend PowerShell because dates are actually dates and not just strings.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell:

```
"{0:yyyy}{1:D2}" -f (get-date),((get-date -uformat %W) -as [Int])
```

Answer (score 1):

without powershell:

```
@echo off

    for /f %%W in (
        'mshta vbscript:Execute("createobject(""scripting.filesystemobject"").GetStandardStream(1).writeline(DatePart(""ww"",Now()))"^^^&close^)'
    ) do @( 
     set "weekn=%%W"
    )

echo %weekn%
set /a weekn=weekn-1
if %weekn% LSS 10 set weekn=0%weekn%
echo %weekn%
```

this is a small part of vbscript executed with mshta.Have on mind that vbscript starts to count weeks from 1 but unix from 0 so you might need to substract 1.

Comment: So how to add this batch script and get output 2 digits number?  And how to substract 1....

Comment: Avoid the ugliness and switch to PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks very much "npocmaka"....your code work really very well.....and this code will run every Monday at 12:01 am will change the week???  Thanks

Comment: @dotran - it should run well independent of the time.